# Jmeter pass number of threads as dynamic value

Tags: multithreading, variables, dynamic, foreach, jmeter

I have a main thread where I am getting a list of categories from there I am passing each category from inside the ForEach Controller to next thread. In this thread I get a number of categories inside the variable

In the second thread I am going through each category and using ForEach Controller to pass each product into the 3rd Thread. In this thread I get a number of products inside the variable.

Now I want to use the above number of categories and products into the second and third threads as a dynamic variable i.e if:
categories are 10 then the second thread numbers should be 10
products are 100 then I would like 100/10 = 10 threads for 3 thread group.

I am using the interthread communication processors successfully which works fine withe static number of threads but not when I pass as a variable via interthread communication processors
Please help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. In first Thread Group define the desired number of threads using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) like:

   ```
   ${__setProperty(threads,10, )}
   ```
2. In second Thread Group read the value using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

   ```
   ${__P(threads,)}
   ```

   [image]
3. That's it, 2nd Thread Group will kick off as many threads as you define in the first one

   [image]

More information: [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups/)

Also be aware that s[ince JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting so convert your Beanshell test elements into JSR223 and make sure to use Groovy